# Can you cash out a battle.net balance?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

Can you transfer funds from your battle.net balance?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer funds from your battle net account too any other means of paying (Paypal, Bank, etc) Once money is on Battle.net you can only use it on battle.net.

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5825482578)

Answer (score 0):

They don't support cashing it out in the normal sense, as Blizzard will not transfer the balance to a bank account for you.  However you can link your account to a Paypal account, and "cash out" your balance to that - this is what the Diablo 3 FAQ is referring to.  There is a 15% transfer fee on that.

This is also not a universal solution.  I believe there may be region/country-specific restrictions on Paypal allowing cashing out of your balance.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  You CANNOT transfer a Battle.net Balance to PayPal.  You must choose one or the other when you post the item.

Comment: @Ramhound The correct answer would be "you cannot transfer ANYMORE"